# Интервал между элементами RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Как увеличить отступ между элементами `RecyclerView`? У меня они находятся слишком близко. Как увеличь интервал между ними?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - пропишите в основном Layout элемента `RecyclerView` параметр `android:layout_margin="10dp"` (или сколько нужно)

Comment: Это то что нужно! Спасибо

Comment: Если используете cardView , то можно настроить отступы для карточки. Я так обычно делаю что бы контейнер RV можно было заюзать повторно